# Merge-SPLogFile not working in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016

Client has a Single Server SharePoint 2016 Farm with about 15 Site Collections on it.

They have an issue I am trying to diagnose but when I try to run Merge-SPLogFile I get an error :-

**'None of the Collecting Jobs finished successfully'**

I've tried restarting the SharePoint Timer Service, an IIS Reset

The command I'm running is this :-

`Merge-SPLogFile -Path "c:\temp\xxxx.log" -Correlation <correlationid error>`

Ran it a thousand times on other environment and never had an issue.At first I thought the syntax might have changed between 2013 and 2016 but the Get-Help file looks the same. 
Any help appreciated in advance. Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that your TimerJob-Instances are down. Please check with the following script:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances
foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers)
{
write-host "Server: " $FT.Server.Name.ToString();
write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs;
write-host "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"
}
```

Use the following Script to start disabled Instances again:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances
foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers)
{
write-host "Server: " $FT.Server.Name.ToString();
write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs;
write-host "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"
}
$disabledTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances | where {$_.Status -ne "Online"}
if ($disabledTimers -ne $null)
{
foreach ($timer in $disabledTimers)
{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Timer service instance on server " $timer.Server.Name " is NOT Online. Current status:" $timer.Status
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Attempting to set the status of the service instance to online..."
$timer.Provision()
$timer.Start()
write-host -ForegroundColor Red "You MUST now go restart the SharePoint timer service on server " $FT.Server.Name}}
else
{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All Timer Service Instances in the farm are online. No problems found!"
}
```

Reference: [SharePoint Timer jobs not running(Specially one-time timer jobs)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sujesh/2017/10/16/sharepoint-timer-jobs-not-runningspecially-one-time-timer-jobs/)

Comment: MHeld - thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the first script didn't return anything. Dan

Comment: Further to this I ran the script here :- https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/5f5db8378c303da87bc4 That returned 'All Timer Service Instances in the Farm are online! No problem found'

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of things which can cause this issue.

- check if SharePoint tracing service is running on the server.
- check if SharePoint Admin service is running on the server.
- Also check from central admin, if their is any time job name `Collection of log files from server "servername`" stuck. CA > Monitoring > Running job status
- You may need to clear the Config cache to get it working.
- I would also check the event log and see if there is any other clue, may be it is permission issue.

Side note, if it is single server farm, and if you know the timing of the correlation id, You can simply get the log file which contains that timing and open it in ULS viewer and filter that file with your correlation id.

Comment: Waqas - thanks for the suggestions, I'll check them out. Dan

Comment: Checked all of the above. SharePoint Tracing is running, SharePoint Admin Service is running, There was no timer job called 'Collection of log files from Server. I reset the Config Cache and this made no difference. Can't see anything in the Event Viewer that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Finally - I used ULS Viewer to see the Correlation Error and found this - No Cache Hosts are present in the Farm.