# Merge-SPLogFile doesn't return any records, but entries are there in SharePoint logs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

When I run the below Merge-SPLogFile it throws me the warning

> WARNING: Cmdlet did not return any records in the log file. Check your
>   time range or filters.

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Correlation 2816f89e-8451-7054-1584-ad125aa03b3 -Path D:\Log.txt
```

But when I checked the SharPoint logs it got messages for same correlation. I exported the logs using ULS viewer, but in my case there are multiple SharePoint WEB & APP Servers

Couple of months ago, it was returning me the records, but now it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

1.Try to not add any filters in the cmdlet, see if it works. like this:

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Path D:\Log.log -Overwrite
```

2.Instead of just asking for the Correlation ID, provide a date filter, the narrower the time span is, the faster it will execute:

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Path D:\Log.log -Correlation "2816f89e-8451-7054-1584-ad125aa03b3" -StartTime "8/7/2019 12:00:00" -EndTime "8/7/2019 15:00:00"
```

Here is a similar post:
[Merge-SPLogFile not working in Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241597/merge-splogfile-not-working-in-powershell)